# $A$ and $B$ are bounded linear operators from the normed linear space $X$ to itself. If $AB$ is invertible are $A$ and $B$ invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I think I understand the proof for square matrices, such that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, but I'm not sure if I can just say the same for the bounded linear operators A and B.

Does the existence of $(AB)^{-1}:X\rightarrow X$ imply the existence of $B^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: I think you meant the existence of $(AB)^{-1}$. You cannot write it in $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ without knowing that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist. Even in the proof for square matrices, you should avoid stating that way before you know $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ exist.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's exactly what I meant.  Thank you for correcting me, I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  For example, define on $\ell^p$
$$
L(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (x_2,x_3,\dots)\\
R(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)
$$
Then $LR = \text{id}_{\ell^p}$ is invertible, but neither $L$ nor $R$ are bijective.

You might be able to say something in the case that both $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible.

Comment: So then how, if you don't mind me asking, would I go about showing the invertibility of A and B given AB and BA invertible?

Comment: Set theory alone is enough to show that $A$ and $B$ must both be bijective if $AB$ and $BA$ are bijective.  I'm not sure about the existence of bounded inverses, though

Comment: If $A,B$ are bounded, and $AB$ and $BA$ have bounded inverses, then both $A$ and $B$ have bounded inverses. If $ABC=I$ and $DBA=I$, then $BC$ is a right-inverse for $A$, and $DB$ is a left-inverse; it follows that $A$ is invertible with $DB=BC=A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false in the general infinite dimensional setting. For example, let $X$ be the Banach space $\ell^p$, and define $A,B$ by$$A(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_2,x_3,\ldots),\qquad B(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots).$$Then $AB$ is the identity, but $A$ and $B$ are not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

For the question in the title, the answer is No. Take $B : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ be the right-shift operator
$$
(x_n) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)
$$
and $A$ to be the left shift
$$
(x_n) \mapsto (x_2,x_3,\ldots)
$$
Then $AB$ is the identity operator, and so invertible, but neither $A$ nor $B$ are invertible.

But later on, you ask about $B^{-1} A^{-1}$ implying the existence of $B^{-1}$ or $A^{-1}$. Not sure what you are asking there.